# Static Maps API adding hue | saturation | lightness breaks image?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, maps

I'm using the Static Google Maps API to create an image, Ideally I would like to add in some hue and saturation styles but when I add these to the url my image breaks. Can anyone advise on where I may be going wrong with this?

HTML

```
<img src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?zoom=14&size=900x600&maptype=road&style=feature:landscape|element:all|visibility:simplified|hue:#e4e4e4&markers=219+4th+Ave+N,+Seattle,+WA+98109|200+2nd+Avenue+NorthSeattle,+WA+98109|325+5th+Ave+N,+Seattle,+WA+98109&sensor=false&visual_refresh=true"></img>
```

JSFiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/pXuXz/2/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hue value should be a RGB hex string of format 0xRRGGBB

```
hue:0xe4e4e4
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nqGY7/

Comment: hey thanks for the reply, is it possible to add featureTypes like road.highway?

Comment: You can add multiple `style` rules with different feature types. http://jsfiddle.net/nqGY7/1/